# How Can I Globally Detect Touch-screen Events in the Windows 8 Metro UI?

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-8

I am developing a WinForms C# application, that needs to know when the computer is not "idle", that is, that a user is actively using it. I can detect keyboard and mouse activity in both the standard desktop and Metro (I think thats what they call it). I can also detect touchscreen activity in the standard desktop - these events are detected as mouse events.

However, using the touchscreen in Metro, none of these events are raised. I have tried this project: http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/ as well as writing code to hook into the Windows SetWindowsHookEx API with no luck.

I spent some time investigating the WinEvents API too, but can't find anything there that will help.

Anybody know if this can be done? And how?

Comment: Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There happens to be a nice [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302%28VS.85%29.aspx) for that but unfortunately it is C++, so you'll have to [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo) it.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, since I want to be notified when an event occurs, not call a function to see if something has occurred. But - I can make this work by calling the function on a timer - and this is the only workable solution I could find, so I will mark this as the answer.